# CIFS VFS warning when transferring between NFS and CIFS

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, cifs

I have a script running on Ubuntu 16 that is used to move text files from an NFS share to a CIFS share.  As part of the process the CR/LF translation is undertaken to support consumption by a windows service that accesses the CIFS share.  The Ubuntu console logs the following for each transfer:

> CIFS VFS: src file seems to be from a different filesystem type

Is this a bad thing - should I be concerned?  I am not really sure what it is telling me other than the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a bug that was reported to Ubuntu's launchpad, titled: [dmesg CIFS VFS: src file seems to be from a different filesystem type for every file i copy/move to shared folder](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1690570).

I see no resolution for this at this point in time.

Comment: Thank you - the files seem to be translated / moved ok - so I will just put up with it for now.